# How to pass jwt token from one microservice to other microservice in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

Scenario : I have 4 microservices

1. Gateway Service
2. Authentication Service
3. Posts Service (internally calls media service)
4. Media Service

I get the token from authentication service which contains user information (name, roles).
Then I call the posts API (via Gateway service) with that token. Now in posts api, I have to call media service and I need to pass the token which I got since i need roles and username in media service api. How can I do this ?

I have checked many resources but could not find how we can attach the token to the rest template.

Comment: May be helpful to see how it's done in [KeycloakRestTemplate](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/client/KeycloakRestTemplate.java) and [KeycloakClientRequestFactory](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/client/KeycloakClientRequestFactory.java)